# FSCalendar: prevent automatic scrolling when date from other month is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, fscalendar

The default behavior of FSCalendar is that if a month is currently being displayed (for example December) and the user taps to select a day from the previous month (November), the calendar will scroll to the previous month.

Is there a way to prevent that automatic scrolling, without disabling selection?

Comment: you need to implement delegate method a date is selected and implement the logic to avoid scrolling by comparing date.

Comment: Thanks @Mahendra, but I believe that when the didSelect delegate method is called, scrolling has already been triggered automatically.

Comment: another option is to disable the selection of the date which is not in current month.

Comment: @Mahendra True. That's what I have done in the meantime, but I need people to be able to select a date from other months too.